# I need to plot a lot of X's on a graph, but is there a way to not have to directly specify the color?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter

I have to plot these x's on a graph, however is there a way to not need to specify the color?
I just plotted a few as an example, but I have specific coordinates.

```
plt.plot(324,66,'x',color='red',markersize=10)
plt.plot(322,65.5,'x',color='blue',markersize=10)
plt.plot(318,63,'x',color='green',markersize=10)
plt.plot(319.5,65,'x',color='purple',markersize=10)
plt.show()
```

[image]

For example, I tried to iterate using a colormap and specify the coordinates by making an array, but it's not matching with the correct location:

```
x1 = 324,66
x2 = 322,65.5
x3 = 319.5,65
x4 = 318,63

points = np.stack((x1,x2,x3,x4))

color= matplotlib.cm.magma(np.linspace(0,1,4))
for i,c in zip(range(4),color):
    plt.plot(points[i],'x')
plt.show()
```

[image]

What might I be doing wrong?
I have to plot a lot of X's, so I don't want to need to specify the color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `seaborn` and use `hue` parameter:

```
x1 = 324,66
x2 = 322,65.5
x3 = 319.5,65
x4 = 318,63
df = pd.DataFrame((x1,x2,x3,x4), columns= ['x', 'y'])
sns.pointplot(x = 'x', y ='y' , data = df , hue = df.index, markers= '*')
```

OUTPUT:

[image]